# Mockito: using when over a mocked Mono with timeout method causes InvalidUseOfMatchersException

Tags: mockito, spring-webclient

I am working on the unit test of a reactive WebClient usage and my problem comes when I try to mock the behavior of Mono with the method timeout(Duration d).

I just want to control the result of a call like:

```
private Mono<String> withTimeout(Mono<String> myMono) {
  return myMono.timeout(Duration.of(globalDuration));
}
```

So I am using this:

```
@Test
void test() {
...
    Mono<String> monoMock = (Mono<String>) Mockito.mock(Mono.class);
    when(monoMock.timeout(Mockito.any(Duration.class))).thenReturn(Mono.just("OK"));
...
}
```

But it generates a

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Misplaces or misused argument matcher detected here:

-> at service.UserServiceTest.test(UserServiceTest.java:98)

You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
    when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
    verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))

This message may appear after an NullPointerException if the last matcher is retur....
```

How should I actually *when* the result of this *Mono.timeout* method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also just experienced this strange error, in addition to your error I also got `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

I was able to solve this by importing:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

After this I was able to simply do this without any issues:

```
var monoMock = Mockito.mock(Mono.class);
lenient().when(monoMock.timeout((any(Duration.class)))).thenReturn(monoMock);
```